# How can I re-create this on my Rasberry PI?

Tags: database, captive-portal

I want to do something similar to Kiwix. Can anybody tell me how I could re-create this myself, or at least the main steps needed to build a similar project?

https://www.kiwix.org/en/

It sounds like kiwix allows you to turn your raspberry Pi into a sort of offline WiFi hotspot that doesn't need a network connection. It allows people to connect to the raspberry pi through Wifi to access your offline database of books, wikipedia articles, etc.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have found this and hopefully it does something similar but much simpiler than kiwix.

**Setting up a Raspberry Pi Captive Portal**: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/

Comment: yes, turn your Pi into an access point - there's about a trillion guides on how to do this

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how do I also allow others to access a database of books and other folders/files when they connect?

Comment: Or maybe create an html website that they can access?

Comment: once you have the wireless hotspot going, you might want to run a web server (nginx, apache, etc) to host html.  After that comes a method of redirecting users to the web pages- this is sometimes done by redirecting all traffic that does not map elsewhere (even if someone goes to google.com, the pi responds with its own page).  There was also something specific for a sort of router login that gets used at hotspots.

Comment: https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-hotspot This link may be help you which have all information that how to create a image file for respberry pi models